# OpenRasta - Incorrect status code returned when the resource uri is incorrect

Tags: c#, .net, rest, http-status-codes, openrasta

I'm using OpenRasta framework in a .net service and I've a method as below in the handler

```
public OperationResult Delete(int Id)
{
  // Do some operation and get an entity
  return new OperationResult.OK(MyResource);
}
```

My configuration looks like below:

```
ResourceSpace.Has.ResourcesOfType<MyResource>()
          .AtUri("/MyResource/{Id}")
          .And.AtUri("/MyResource")
          .HandledBy<MyResourceHandler>()
          .AsJsonDataContract().ForMediaType("application/json")
          .And.AsXmlDataContract().ForMediaType("application/xml");
```

My request is framed as below

```
HttpMethod: DELETE
AcceptHeader: "application/xml"
URI: http://localhost/MyResource/a
```

Please observe the resource parameter: delete method accepts integer whereas I'm passing a character.

With this request I expected 404 status code instead I got 405 Method not allowed. Can anybody explain this behavior, why it is returning 405?

If I give incorrect resource name in the URI it returns me 404. for ex: `URI:http://localhost/OtherResource/a`

**Update**: I'm testing this using OpenRasta's InMemoryHost and Delete method is supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the behavior to be correct. The URI entered matches one OpenRasta owns, and you have a method in which the Id is an int. The URI gets parsed and no method on the registration can be executed (none of them have a string as the Id), so OR is out of choices and know that while the resource has been registered, there is no method it can execute with the current request, hence the 405.

Comment: Thanks for the information. After reading through HTTP specification, I'm even more confused about this. Anyway specification says that response MUST include allow header containing a list of valid methods for this resource. Is OR sending allow header? I couldn't find any as such.

Comment: No that's something we don't provide so far for various techncial reasons. It'll get fixed though.